# Why do some Arduino relay modules can handle up to 250 VAC but not above 30 VDC?

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, relay, ac-dc

When you look for "Arduino relay module"s, you usually see one form "SONGLE" that says on it:

```
10A 250 VAC    10A 125 VAC  
10A 30  VDC    10A 28  VDC
```

**My question:**

- Why do some Arduino relay modules can handle up to 250 VAC but not above 30 VDC?

Comment: Because of arcing. AC arcs auto-extingush when the waveform crosses 0V. DC don't.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on this comment and post it as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: No, because the question has already been asked, and answered, before. Just read the answer given to the previous question (linked above).

Comment: Then why bother in first place?!